# How can you logically verify if firebase 'child_added' data exists and provide logic to process?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have logic that I need to check on finding an existing child node. If the node is found, I need to reference the key, etc. If it's not found, I want to do something else programmatically. I've have read other postings that say use the snap.exists() to determine this...which I have tried in the code below. But for some reason, the code skips this reference and does not run the internal logic.

If I change "child_added" to "value", it will will run exists code, but then it doesn't contain the snap.key value I need from the child node.

There must be easy way to code this?

```
    firebase.database().ref('users').child(props.currentUser.uid).child('traits').orderByChild('field').equalTo(traitName).once('child_added', snap => {

    if (snap.exists())
    {
        console.log('found');
    } 
    else{
        console.log('did not find');
    }
}).then(() => {
    runprocess(traitName, traitValue);
});
```

Comment: There is no way to determine is there's no data with just `child_*`, you will need a `value` listener for that. To process the multiple children that a `value` event gets, you can use `snapshot.forEach(function(child) { console.log(child.key); })`. But you can also combine `child_*` and `value` events. Firebase will only retrieve the data once behind the scenes, so there's no penalty to having multiple listeners for the same data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to determine is there's no data with just `child_*`, you will need a `value` listener for that.

To process the multiple children that a `value` event gets, you can use:

```
firebase.database().ref('users').child(props.currentUser.uid).child('traits').orderByChild('field').equalTo(traitName).once('value', snapshot => {
  if (snap.exists()) {
    console.log('found');
    snapshot.forEach(function(child) { 
      console.log(child.key); 
    })
  } 
  else{
    console.log('did not find any children');
  }
})
```

If you only care about whether any child exists, and don't need the other children, you can limit the query to one result:

```
firebase.database().ref('users')
     .child(props.currentUser.uid).child('traits')
     .orderByChild('field').equalTo(traitName)
     .limitToFirst(1)
     .once('value', snapshot => {
```

But you'll still need the `forEach` call here, since the API doesn't know that there will be only result - or at least it has no overload for that situation.

You can also combine `child_*` and `value` events. Firebase will only retrieve the data once behind the scenes, so there's no penalty to having multiple listeners for the same data.

Comment: tried, but my reputation is too low...pretty new to the site.